# TraditionalForm overriding settings given to Column for row alignment

Tags: display, alignment, traditional-form

With the code below, the alignment at the equal sign is performed as expected:

```
Column[{HoldForm[y] == x, HoldForm[R^2] == 0.998}, Alignment -> "\[Equal]"]
```

[image]

However, when the code was modified to display in `TraditionalForm`:

```
Column[TraditionalForm /@ {HoldForm[y] == x, HoldForm[R^2] == 0.998}, 
  Alignment-> "\[Equal]"]`
```

the alignment is broken:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Will `TraditionalForm` unpredictably break the column alignment in the output?
2. Is there a way to display equations in `TraditionalForm` aligned at the equal sign inside `Column`? I want to embed the equations inside graphics with `Inset`

I knew some workarounds such as the `Row` structuring, but want to have a simpler (if possible) version. And I'm curious why the `Alignment->"marker"` syntax will fail with `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: Separate to this question you may want to consider using `Defer`: `Column[{Defer[y == x], Defer[R^2 == 0.998]}, Alignment -> "\[Equal]"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you gave `"\[Equal]"` as the centering character, but you should have given `"\[LongEqual]"`.

```
Column[TraditionalForm /@ {HoldForm[y] == x, HoldForm[R^2] == 0.998}, 
  Alignment -> "\[LongEqual]"]
```

[image: labels]

To see that `TraditionalForm` replaces `==` with "[LongEqual]", you can open up the output cell your code produces by clicking on Show Expression from the Cell menu (<kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on OS X).

Comment: May be worthwhile adding a screen grab of the underlying boxes so that we can see that `TraditionalForm` creates the `\[LongEqual]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch. That makes for a messy-looking answer. I hope my update is a satisfactory substitute.